# Mongoose how to find docs within two different dates?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

This is my weather model:

```
// Declare schema
var weatherSchema = Schema({
    data: {
        type: Object
    },
    date: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    created_at: {
        type: Date,
        default: Date.now,
        index: 1
    }
});
```

in `date` field, I store dates such as 2017-7-1, 2017-7-2, 2017-7-3, etc

Now I have many docs in this weather table, from 2017-6-20 to 2017-7-3 for instance.

So I want to retrieve the docs from `2017-7-1` to `2017-7-2` only:

```
Weather
.find({})
.where('date').gt('2017-7-1').lt('2017-7-2')
.exec(function (err, docs) {
    console.log(docs);
    if (err) {
        res.set('Content-Type', 'application/json');
        return res.sendStatus(-1);
    }

    if (!docs) {
        res.set('Content-Type', 'application/json');
        return res.status(200).send('Not weather data found.');
    }
    // return docs as json.
    return res.status(200).json(docs);
});
```

But what I get is `[]`. What have I done wrong?

Any ideas?

**EDIT:**

The [official format above](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/queries.html) **does not** work, but it works with this format:

```
var options =  {
    "date": {
        "$gte": start,
        "$lt": end
    }
}

Weather
.find(options, function (err, docs) {
    console.log(docs);
    if (err) {
        res.set('Content-Type', 'application/json');
        return res.status(200).send('Error occurs: ' + err);
    }

    if (!docs) {
        res.set('Content-Type', 'application/json');
        return res.status(200).send('Not weather data found.');
    }
    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET,POST,DELETE');

    // return docs as json.
    return res.status(200).json(docs);
}).select("-created_at -_id -__v");
```

Why?

Answer (score 1):

To compare a dates the `date` field should be a `Date` type. and then you can search like:

```
.where('date').gt(new Date('2017-7-1')).lt(new Date('2017-7-2'))
```

Or If you want use date as a string, you can search like this:

```
.where('date').in(['2017-7-1', '2017-7-2'])
```

This query will find entries with exact date string ('2017-7-1' or '2017-7-2')

Comment: thanks but it does not work. I am on mongoose 4.9.1.